# change pseudo element :before with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, pseudo-element

Is it possible to change a CSS pseudo element in JS?

This is my CSS code

```
.lang-menu .selected-lang:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background-image: url(../img/icons/armenia-flag-round-icon-32.png);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Here is my JS code

```
function changeCss() {
let elem = window.getComputedStyle(selLang, ':before');
elem.backgroundImage = "url(../img/icons/united-states-of-america-flag-round-icon-32.png'))"
}
changeCss()
```

Comment: No. A pseudo element is not in the DOM and so cannot be selected by Javascript

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49618941/8620333